# Cordova Android application getting "invalid_client" from MobileFirst 8.0 server

Tags: android, cordova, oauth-2.0, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

My Cordova IOS application integrated with IBM MobileFirst v8 works fine. However I face a weird issue with **Android**.

The scenario is,
The user has to login into security check to access the application.

The challenge handler is called and credentials are submitted to (runtime/api/preauth/v1/preauthorize). I see in the logs security check is passed.

I can see the next call to authorization end point (runtime/api/az/v1/authorization)

However I see a difference between Android and IOS in the parameters passed to this end point.

**Android**

```
    response_type=code
    scope=
    client_id=
    redirect_uri=http://mfpredirecturi&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.9217767383903592
```

The subsequent call to token generation end point fails for Android alone.
/runtime/api/az/v1/token HTTP/1.1" 400
{status: 400, errorCode: "invalid_client", description: "Incorrect JWT format"}

**IOS**

```
    response_type=code
    scope=
    client_id=
    redirect_uri=http%3A//mfpredirecturi
```

WLAuthorizationManager.login(SECURITY_CHECK_NAME, credential) triggers /preauthorize call

cordova-mfp-plugin (8.0.2016110713)
cordova-android (5.2.0)

my primary suspect is redirect_uri which is not encoded for Android alone. is the one causing the problem? is it possible to encode and send the redirect_uri from cordova application?

Comment: What is the first operation that triggered the preauthorize in your app? (resource request / obtain / login etc). We're trying to reproduce. Also, can you check the version of the cordova-mfp-plugin?

Comment: WLAuthorizationManager.login(SECURITY_CHECK_NAME, credential) is the one that triggered the  preauthorize.

Comment: I use the latest version of cordova-mfp-plugin (8.0.2016110713).

Comment: Could you also provide the version of `cordova-android`. Check by typing `cordova platform`. Add all the information by editing the question.

Comment: I  couldn't figure out this issue. No clue. Any help and pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @vinesh-sn if you are a customer, I suggest opening a PMR in the meantime.

Comment: @VigneshSn: did you open a PMR?

Comment: @IdanAdar I took this issue to my organization for validation. Will raise PMR soon.

Comment: @VigneshSn, was a PMR opened? What is its number?

Comment: @IdanAdar  PMR Opened (79626 000 834)

Comment: @IdanAdar Is there any solution to this problem? We have also came across same problem.

Comment: The PMR is still open. You can open another saying you experience the same.

Comment: @IdanAdar I am getting the same issue .. any solution ? If anyone opened a PMR then how can we check that ?

Comment: Any update? was this fixed? We are having the same issue on one of our projects, can you share how this was resolved for you?

Comment: Well I could not find a solution but if you need to have it running temporarily, I have found a hack.
Change the time on your client device from T (Where T is the actual time) to T+15mins. Its just a temporary fix.

Comment: I've also encountered this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try newer MFP adapter plugin 
in your pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins> 
        <plugin> 
            <groupId>com.ibm.mfp</groupId>
            <artifactId>adapter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.2017021701</version> 
            <extensions>true</extensions> 
        </plugin> 
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This adapter plugin version works fine.